# image is not set on UIButton in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

when i pass static value in **bktheme[1]** then image is properly set on button.

when i already get value from NSUserDefaults and set as bktheme as under

```
Defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()         
       let shape  = Defaults.integerForKey("Chaperone")
       print(shape)    // output: 1
       let str = bkthemes[shape]

       keyImageTypeOne = UIImage(named: str) as UIImage?
```

then image is not set so, how can i set image on button

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.

If you get image name in **str** then only below code works.

So i want to suggest you at first print value of **str** in console.

```
Defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let shape = Defaults.integerForKey("Chaperone")
print(shape)    // output: 1
let str = bkthemes[shape]
yourButton.setImage(UIImage(named: str), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

If you get any issue then give me value of **str**.

Comment: str value is image name like (key_pad@2x.png) and i want to set background image on uibutton

Answer (score 1):

your code is fine just do like

```
keyImageTypeOne.setImage(UIImage(named: str) as UIImage?, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: i got problem my uiinputview is not reload can you give me any idea how can i reload it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
let button:UIButton =  UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
let image:UIImage = UIImage(named:"nope")!
button.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```